# Form_Load() 'event' or Override OnLoad()

Tags: .net, winforms, events, refactoring, overriding

I would like someone to try and explain the difference between these.  More specifically, example usage scenario's.

I am refactoring some **Windows Form** code and a `Form` has some code in the `Form_Load()` event and also in a `protected override void OnLoad()` event that calls `base.OnLoad(e);`  Now I traced it and the Override fires first and then immediately fires off the event version.

So, which one is typically used and why?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521322/what-setup-code-should-go-in-form-constructors-versus-form-load-event

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should always override OnLoad().  Using the event is only appropriate when *another* class would be interested in the event.  Which is what events are for.  Another class being interested in the Load event is very rare, only really useful to do window arrangement stuff.

Still, the Load event works well with the designer and VB6 programmers are very comfortable with it.  It isn't horribly wrong, you'd only get in trouble when you start inheriting the form and code doesn't run in the right order.

Most code that now gets put in the Load event really belongs in the constructor.  You only need OnLoad if:

- You need to know the exact size and position of the window.  OnLoad is best, the window Handle is created and the user preferences are applied (title and border size) and the form was rescaled as directed by the Form.AutoScaleMode property.  The window is not yet visible, a very good time to move the window somewhere else or to arrange the child controls.
- You have code that needs the Handle property.  This is subtle, you cannot always tell.  Having code like that in the constructor is unhealthy, the window gets created before the constructor completed.  It usually comes to a good end but it can make creating the form very slow.  Easy to diagnose from the Call Stack window.
- To avoid a bug in the MDI implementation.  If you create an MDI child in the parent constructor then you'll get duplicated glyphs, visible when you maximize the child.  Create the child in OnLoad instead.

Comment: So, stop me if I am wrong, but it is more "correct" to use the `OnLoad()` but I would need to be cognizant of the fact that the code in there would not be available to another class.  Correct?

Comment: It *is* available to a derived class, base.OnLoad().  Skipping the initialization of the base class would almost always be wrong.  *Another* class has no business with the code in Load/OnLoad.

Comment: So if a derived class call `OnLoad()` it would fire `base.OnLoad()` and then any code I put after that.

Comment: A derived class never calls OnLoad, that's goes kaboom.  Always base.OnLoad().

Comment: Can I sum up your answer as use `OnLoad()` except when explicitly needed otherwise.

Comment: +1, nice answer. Related: where would you put cleanup code (like deregistering even handlers)? Overriding OnFormClosed?

Comment: @sne - yes, same logic applies.

Comment: @Hans Passant: well, I was wondering whether you'd suggest something else (overriding Dispose?) since you suggest putting other initialization in the constructor rather than overriding OnLoad :)

Comment: @sne - a good answer doesn't fit in a comment box.  I recommend you  start your own thread.

Comment: This seems related in my mind: When would you perform data access in a class which inherits UserControl that resides on a Form with multiple tabbed UserControls? I have been using OnLoad to defer access until that tab's visilibity is requested as opposed to a large pause when the form is first loaded and all UserControls are constructed. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

When overriding `OnLoad`, the call to `base.OnLoad` invokes the `Load`-event of the Form.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // do stuff before Load-event is raised
  base.OnLoad(e);
  // do stuff after Load-event was raised
}
```

If you don't specifically need to perform stuff before the Load-event is raised, placing the code in `OnLoad` *after* `base.OnLoad(e)` gives the same runtime behaviour as placing it in the `Form_Load` event handler.

I would recommend overriding the method rather than subscribing to the event.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it sounds like you are saying there isn't a definitive answer to my question beyond timing of the Form Loading, correct?

Comment: I would personally override the OnLoad method, since this is the typical approach when creating inherited classes. The events are, as mentioned by Hans Passant, meant for other classes who can subscribe to these. But in practice there is no real difference.

Answer (score 0):

`OnLoad` raises the *Load* event, which `Form_Load` handles.  See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx).

So, in your code, at the end of your initialization function, you could call the `OnLoad` function.  The base class will then call your event handlers (`Form_Load` in this case), which you may have set in your initialization code.

Personally, I would place my code in the `Form_Init` and leave `OnLoad` for initiating the event, since I'm handling the event, although you can defend either with good reason, as you see from your answers.

Comment: I may be dense but I think you are confirming what I said about OnLoad calling the Load Event but does this answer my question about which one I should be placing my code in?  It seems, to me, that I can put it in either with equal effect as long as it is after the `base.OnLoad(e)` call.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question, which is not on whether to *call* `OnLoad` but on whether to *override* it.