# Form_Disposed event Vs Form_Closing event in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know Form_Disposed event Vs Form_Closing event in VB.net.When I call application.exit function , the application is call form_closing event and form_disposed event in my computer.But I try to run this exe on remote server , the application does not work form_closing event.It it only run form_dispose event.I would like to know why application does not call form_closing event and different between closing and disposed event

Comment: What operating system is the server running? What .NET framework are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Me.FormClosing works on some forms but not others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235192/me-formclosing-works-on-some-forms-but-not-others)

Comment: @cybermonkey,My computer is window 7 Ultimate and .NET framework 1.1

Comment: Not *your* computer, the ***server's***. `.NET Framework 1.1` is *incredibly* old. Install .NET 4.5.