# windows form make a form starts at a specific position

Tags: css, winforms, forms

I made a simple program with two forms. the first form is small, the second one is large.

I already handled the screen resolution thing so the scroll is working and I tested the application on many screen sizes and resolutions.

my problem is this:

when I go from the first form to the second form, the second form doesn't start from the top left of the screen so the result is this:
[image]

I have to drag it to the top to see the two buttons at the bottom like this:
[image]

my question is: is there a way to make this form starts as in the second image, not the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forms.StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx) is the property to work with.

Usually setting it to `CenterParent` or `CenterScreen` should work well for your requirement.
Instead if you want to fine tune the position of the form then you should set the property to `Manual` and then work with the `Location` property (a Point structure) calculating the correct location desidered.

Also, keep in mind that if you want to manually work with Location and Size of the form you should do it overriding the OnLoad event, [as explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670806/form-load-event-or-override-onload)

Comment: I went to the property of the form and changed the start position to center parent but still the same problem , the cancel and save buttons doesn't appear until i drag the form up

Comment: you know what? the center screen helps me, thanks I will accept the answer when the system allows

Comment: @Youness oh you are the same guy who answered me in my previous quesiton right? sorry really sorry, in both cases I couldn't accept yoru answer, but when I have enough reputations, I will upvote your answers.

Comment: dont worry i dont care about the votes and stuff :D i just like to help as i can :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a proprety called StartPosition with it you can define the startup position of a form

**PS :** if you want a costum position for exemple if you wan it to be in the coordinate : X=15 and Y =20
in the FormLoad Event (double click the form ;) ) put this :

```
Form1.Location = new Point(15, 20);
```

OR THIS :

```
Form1.Top=20;
Form1.Left=15;
```

Comment: thanks for the efforts, but sorry there is another guy answered me first. i wish i could accept more than answer

Comment: its not for the accept thing :) i saw him before i answered i just wanted to give the extra infos ;)

Comment: Just ""God"" works with the intent. we must deal with facts. I believe you really, but my belief won't increase your reputation :)

Comment: its ok :) and i dont look to increase it :) btw i see you are learning C# good luck its a good language if you need any help just let me know :)

Comment: Appreciate the help though I hate c# because I'm not good at it. However, this is just a small application. I am a JAVA, Python fan. thanks again

Comment: will if you are stuck in that application and need some help just say :) and good luck

Comment: may you help me here please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219654/c-sharp-print-right-to-left

Comment: can we pass to chat so you explain to me the problem in details ?