# c# print right to left

Tags: c#, .net, printing, arabic

I am working with some arabic data and I want to print it from right to left

I tried this

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataToPrint, valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 20, 20, format);
```

but that makes the text to still start from the left and it makes it **worse** so now I **can't see all the text** like this:

[image]

but when I remove the `format`, I got this:

[image]

I need to have exactly as the second image but from right to left.

any help please?

Update 1 
This is how I fill the `dataToPrint` object

```
 System.Drawing.Font valueFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
                string dataToPrint = "";
                dataToPrint += "رقم بطاقة التسويق = " + farmID.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "إسم صاخب المزرعة = " + farmOwner.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "رقم المزرعة = " + farmNumber.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "الموبايل = " + farmMobile.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "الإمارة = " + emaraNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "المنطقة = " + areaNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "الإقليم = " + regionNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "مركز الإستلام = " + receivingCenterName.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "خلاص = " + khalas.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "فرض = " + fardh.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "لولو = " + otherLulu.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += " خنيزي= " + khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "بومعان = " + boumaan.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "برحي = " + barhi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "جش خزمة = " + jeshKharma.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "رزيز = " + reziz.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "جبري = " + jabri.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "عنبرة المدينة = " + anbaretAlMadina.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += " شيشي= " + shishi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "دباس = " + dabbas.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "نبتة سيف = " + nabtetSaif.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "خضراوي = " + khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "هلالي = " + hilali.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "مكتومي = " + maktoumy.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                dataToPrint += "نميشي = " + namishi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
```

#### Update 2

After `@Reyhaneh SH` answer I change the 20 to 400 and this is the result, still not from right to left

[image]

Comment: When you draw RTL then you should be explicit where R is located.  Use the overload that takes a Rectangle argument.  Same issue with mixing Western and Arabic glyphs, if you are not explicit and leave it up to the OS to figure out which parts should be LTR and which RTL then accidents can happen, particularly with punctuation.  Use the "\u200e" before text that should be LTR, "\u200f" for RTL.

Comment: @HansPassant the `dataToPrint` variable has many strings some of them arabic and some of them english and each one has environt.newline so I can go to new line . so could you tell me where to put your unicode? at the beginning of my `dataToPrint` ?

Comment: No, it needs to be inserted in the string, wherever the Arabic or Western text starts.  Clearly you'll need to know enough about the string content to do this correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant I want all the string to be from right to left, I don't know any text to be from left to right. I will try to give you more code

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the question, please check, all the values start with arabic word

Comment: @HansPassant please check my updated question. is there a way to make al the lines have the same space before the values?

Comment: I just change my default printer from "Nova PDF" to "Microsoft Print to PDF" and now I have the right to left text "سلام".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your codes are right, but the problem is that you used 20 pixels for the X position. X specifies the location from upper-left. Try it with :

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString(dataToPrint, valueFont, 
        System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 200, 20, format);
```

You can also use any other numbers bigger than 20 pixels that is proper.

Comment: now it looks better but the content still from left to right not from right to left. got me please? i could show you the result if you want

Comment: Yes please, if it's possible,

Comment: OK, all of the lines are aligned from the right, exactly like the first picture. You need just try bigger number to achieve a location on the right. If it's not what you want, so what do you want?!!

Comment: maybe if i tried bigger number like 10000, and the user use a small page size, the content won't appear, right?

Comment: Of course view will changes in different size in PDF, but if you align your text in 100% size, user can see them same as you in 100%. So I don't think so, but you can try it in another computer if you want to be sure and I would like to know the result.

Comment: +1 and I will accept yoru answer but please how to make it 100% ?

Comment: When you're trying to test, set the size to 100%, or actual size, but in my opinion 100% is more common. http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-08/69776171715458978606.jpg