# Injection custom class in Form windows C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I built the standard windows form application. Just one form with button "Check data".

After click that I send request to Http server and get back data.

I have to execure at once when form was built.

For this I have created separated custom class: CustomRequest.

How to inject this class inside:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     // Create instance of my custom class here
}
```

Is it good practic to inject direectly? Does it break SOLID priciples? Or I need to create also abstract class and use custom class through it?
`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case. Ask yourself these questions:

- Does my code perform operations on the UI?
- Does my code require information from the form or **about** the form?
- Does my code perform a time consuming operation?

If the answer to any of these is yes, then I think the best solution is to override the [OnLoad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload(v=vs.110).aspx) method and execute the code you want there. This is debatable regarding the time consuming code case. However, if your code performs *any* operation on the UI, you should definitely take this approach.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{ 
  // Your code here
}
```

**NOTE:** You can also subscribe to the [Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event, which will yield a similar result, but is only recommended for very specific cases.

If your code isn't related to the UI itself, then using the constructor is the simplest solution, and will likely work just fine. However, there are a few caveats to this approach. First off, you have to remember that the constructor runs when the form is *instantiated*, regardless of whether or not its ever displayed. Additionally, make sure that you place that code *after* the call to `InitializeComponent()`, to prevent any delays in opening the form.

I'm giving you the succinct version. For a more detailed explanation, I recommend you give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522999/7662085) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670912/7662085) answer by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) a quick read. He has some great information about the difference between `Load` and `OnLoad`, as well as when to use one of those two and when to use the constructor.