# Add calculated value to DatagridView from getting value from another datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an vb.net windows application that has some values which i entered through textbox.
And two datagridviews, in that in first datagridview ,when i enter values in all columns, i have a formula which takes value from Textboxes and DatagridView1 column values. These calculated value should display in second datagridview columns.
For this i tried two ways but both showing problem.
    First try:

```
//First Datagridview -LogCalcEnter , Second Datagrid - LogCalValue

    Private Sub LogCalcEnter_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles LogCalcEnter.CellValueChanged

    LogCalValue.Rows(intRow).Cells(0).Value = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(0).Value * fPorCutoff.Text   

    LogCalValue.Rows(intRow).Cells(1).Value = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(1).Value * fSWCutoff.Text

        End Sub
```

When executing the application,before showing the form below  error occurs at

`Me.MainForm = Global.LogCalculation.Form1` in     OnCreateMainForm().

> Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See
>   Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Index was out of
>   range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

So i tried another option i have button in form, when i press button,then depends on number of rows in first grid view i will set the values for second datagrid.
But it works if i have one row in Datagridview1. If more than one row, it shows error at second row.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
        Dim oLog As New Log    
        oLog.sWellName = tWellname.Text
        oLog.fPoroCutoff = fPorCutoff.Text
        oLog.fSWCutOff = fSWCutoff.Text
        oLog.fN = fN.Text
        oLog.fM = fM.Text
        oLog.fA = fA.Text
        oLog.fRW = fRW.Text    
        For iRow = 0 To LogCalcEnter.Rows.Count - 1
            If (Trim(LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(0).Value) <> "" And Trim(LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(1).Value) <> "" And Trim(LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(2).Value) <> "") Then   

                LogCalValue.Rows(iRow).Cells(0).Value = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(0).Value * oLog.fPoroCutoff
                LogCalValue.Rows(iRow).Cells(1).Value = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(1).Value * oLog.fSWCutOff
                LogCalValue.Rows(iRow).Cells(2).Value = LogCalcEnter.Rows(iRow).Cells(2).Value * oLog.fN

            End If
        Next iRow    
    End Sub
```

Actually i want the first option only. But here these two cases get failed.

Answer (score 0):

In the first event, your intRow & iRow may not be defined.

Try this instead,

```
LogCalValue.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value = LogCalcEnter.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value * fPorCutoff.Text   

LogCalValue.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value = LogCalcEnter.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value * fSWCutoff.Text
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887232/error-inside-of-application-designer-vb-inside-of-oncreatemainform-sub), it could be related to your issue.