# The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified

Tags: c#, winforms

To load my ComboBox at the beginning I used the mine method `LoadDataFromDB()` in the `InitializeComponent()` method, but there is an warning says:

> The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the
>   designer and should not be manually modified

So **where can I load my ComboBox?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use form's constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadDataFromDB();
}
```

Or ([sometimes better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199504/how-should-the-form-load-event-be-used-compared-to-its-constructor-method)) [Form.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler (it will be added automatically when you double-click form in designer):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadDataFromDB();
}
```

Another option is overriding `OnLoad` method of form.

NOTE: You see this warning, because `InitializeComponent` is generated by designer, and it will be completely re-generated when you'll change something in designer (add some control, move or resize some control, change color etc). Thus all your changes to this method will gone.

Answer (score 3):

Directly after InitializeComponent is called, or as long as its after InitializeComponent().

```
public FormName()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   LoadDataFromDB();
}
```

Note: You may not see these controls in the Visual studio designer view

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to load it in `InitializeComponent` method. Just after it you can call your method `LoadDataFormDB()`.

```
InitializeComponent();
LoadDataFormDB();
```

You can read also, the comments above the method which says:

```
'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer. 
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
```